# In what object can i add both lists and floats so i can find the list with the lowest float value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, object, iteration

Say i have some iterations. In each iteration, a list of integers and a float number are created.

```
1st iteration: [0,2,4,3,0] , 285 are created
2nd iteration: [0,8,5,6,0] , 230 are created
...
nth iteration: [0,9,8,1,0] , 340 are created
```

I want to iteratively append each list-float pair to an object, so I can later get the list with the lowest float value.
Desired output could be for example something like this:

```
ListColumn, FloatColumn
[0,2,4,3,0], 285
[0,8,5,6,0], 230
...
[0,9,8,1,0], 340
```

I tried to append these lists and floats to a dictionary (with floats as keys) but since some floats can be equal, the number of elements inside the dictionary is less than expected. Any ideas?

Comment: List-of-lists or list-of-tuples? `data = [([0,2,4,3,0], 285), ([0,8,5,6,0], 230), ([0,9,8,1,0], 340)]` Then to find the smallest by the float value: `min(data, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could still create a dictionary, but if the float value is already in the dictionary, you append it to the existing lists.

```
# create dictionary
d = {}

for i in range(n):
    # get your float value and list from somewhere
    float_value, l = create_float_and_list()
    # if the float value already exists, append the new lists to the existing lists, otherwise create new dictionary entry
    if float_value in d.keys():
        d[float_value].append(l)
    else:
        d[float_value] = [l]

float_values = list(d.keys())
min_value = min(float_values)
# output list of lists with the given float value
print(d[min_value])
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to iteratively append each list-float pair to an object, so I can later get the list with the lowest float value.

Reading the motivation literally, "so I can later get the list with the lowest float value,"
suggests that you don't want a data structure at all.
Rather, you want to simply assign `minimum = float('inf')`
(or assign it the 1st value),
and then keep assigning `smallest_list` to be each
list you encounter that is associated with smaller
value than `minimum`.

But if you really really want to create a large data structure
for this, a list of tuples would be a good fit.

```
def get_pairs():
    # Presumably some `for` loop knows how to generate these for real.
    yield 285, [0,2,4,3,0]
    yield 230, [0,8,5,6,0]
    ...
    yield 340, [0,9,8,1,0]


val, lst = sorted(get_pairs())[0]  # The zero-th element has the minimum.
print(lst)
```